# Do NOT want to use geometry notes for material assignment

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

I do not want to use a node in geometry nodes (GN) to assign a material to the object.
But when using GN, the object shows no color. It has to be done with the node "Set Material".

Is there a GN node that has a material input whatever material I assign in the tap 'Material properties'?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are using a Geometry nodes Cube, not a Cube Mesh (the one with the color), that's why you are not getting the same color as the red cube. if you want your cubes to have the same color as your cube mesh, you need to use that object inside geometry nodes instead of the "Cube Node". Also, your questions is bit confusing, your title said that you dont want to use GeoNodes to assign the material, but the question is asking for a Node to input the material.

Comment: setting the material link to 'object' and assigning that on the original cube is sufficient, just as one user has answered here before. That's the sole purpose of `link material to object`, it frees you from whatever the mesh data is assigned to. Just tried that myself in Blender 3.4.1 and can confirm this works

Comment: how do I set the material link to 'object' and assign that on the original cube? 
I added a new file, there is just one cube, no Geometry nodes Cube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Blender 3.4.1 for this at the time of writing my answer. You can assign the material to the `object` instead of the `object data`. There is a dropdown on the right that you'll need to switch over. Once done, you'll need to again specify the `RED` material in the list:

[image: assign to object]

The result with your .blend file:
[image]

Screenshot of your file:
[image: red cube]

Comment: I think this only works for a single material, probably the reason why Vagabonk deleted his answer. It's weird and I wonder what's the explanation, I'd think either object materials wouldn't work at all, or all would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the material information saved on the mesh like so:

[image]